# Entity Framework core: Invalid column name

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this database model:

```
public partial class Image
{
    public Image()
    {
        EntityImages = new List<EntityImage>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EntityImage> EntityImages { get; set; }
}

public partial class EntityImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EntityId")]
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ImageId")]
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

I used database first, and when I am trying to make an insert into Images tables, I got the "Invalid column name: EntityId" error.
This is the context code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityImage>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedBy).HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Entity)
                .WithMany(p => p.EntityImages)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.EntityId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_CategorySubcategory_Entities");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Image)
                .WithMany(p => p.EntityImages)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ImageId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_CategorySubcategory_Images");
        });

modelBuilder.Entity<Image>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Content)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedBy).HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedDate).HasColumnType("datetime");
        });
```

I do not know where the error is.
I do not know why Entity Framework try to insert a image record with a EntityId column since it columns does not exists in that table.

I have the same model for categories, subcategories and categoriesSubcategories tables and the code work without any problems.

Comment: Does your `EntityImage` table in the db actually have a column named `EntityId`?

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett no it does not

Comment: I think that is your answer, then. How are you linking `Entity`s to `EntityImage`s in the database? If `EntityId` has a different name in the database, you'll probably want to update your model property name to match it.